# jQuery clearInterval undifined variable scope issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a script to check if a file exists every 5s in the onclick event  When it exists, I notify the client and reset the counter. The scripts works but the issue is that `clearInterval` doesn't reset the counter once the file exists (*uncaught ReferenceError: intervalCheck is not defined*), so it keeps alerting that the file is found. I'm aware it's a scope issue but I'm not sure how to fix it. Please help! :)

```js
function isFileExists(file) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'HEAD',
        url: '/apps/'+file,
        success: function() {
            alert('found');
            clearInterval(intervalCheck);
        },  
        error: function() {
        }
    });
}

$('#dialog').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var file = $(e.relatedTarget).data('file');
    $("a#checkfile").click(function() { var intervalCheck = setInterval(function() { isFileExists(file); },5000); });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `intervalCheck` in global scope:

```
    var intervalCheck;  

    function isFileExists(file) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'HEAD',
            url: '/apps/'+file,
            success: function() {
                alert('found');
                clearInterval(intervalCheck);
            },  
            error: function() {
            }
        });
    }

    $('#dialog').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        var file = $(e.relatedTarget).data('file');
        $("a#checkfile").click(function() { /* note: var is removed */ intervalCheck = setInterval(function() { isFileExists(file); },5000); });
    });
```